# Isn't my compiled Solidity contract in the JSON format supposed to have a bytecode field? Because it doesn't

Tags: solidity

I do not have a bytecode field in my JSON file... I don't know why. I just had a warning saying my contract may be a bit too big upon compilation. I compiled with Remix. What can cause the issue if any?

Comment: Can you share the contract code and the json file? It could be that the compilation failed for some other reason.

Comment: Can I PM you somewhere @Ismael because I cannot compile my contract anymore since I switched to Github imports? There is a nonsical error: `Type error type struct IHederaTokenService.Expiry memory is not implicily convertible to expected type struct IHederaTokenService.Expiry memory`